# ¿Por qué el archivo tslint.json y la carpeta e2e no se crean automáticamente al ejecutar ng new?

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo una simple (espero) duda, es un poco especifico asi que no pude encontrar informacion al respecto.

Quiero comenzar un nuevo proyecto en Angular y actualicé mi versión angular cli a 13.2.3, para tener la última versión angular para el proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ejecutar el comando "ng new" he notado que no se está creando ni el archivo tslint.json ni el e2e.

Así que estoy un poco confundido sobre por qué sucede esto con esta versión de angular cli, ya que no he encontrado nada que diga que estos archivos no deberían crearse.

Answer (score 1):

> Es una desicion de los desarrolladores de Angular antes se usaba
> **Protactor** por default al construir la aplicacion en la carpeta e2e con
> su protractor.conf.js es asi que ya  no se incluye mas en nuevos proyectos en
> una encuesta menos del 20% de los encuestados usaban Protractor y la
> mayoria como herramienta de testin e2e utilizaban **Cypress** asi en
> Angular 12 no se incluye Protractor y se dan opciones
>
> mediante  la utilizacion de 3rd party solutions de Angular CLI

[Guia uso de protractor en Angular 12](https://danielk.tech/home/angular-12-and-protractor)
[o usando schematics cypress](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2021/05/05/migrating-from-protractor-to-cypress/)

Tambien deprecate **TSLint**  y se admite la migracion a **ESLint**
.TSLint solo se usa con TypeScript mientras ESLint sporta JS y Typescript es uno de los motivos que dan

[ng add @angular-eslint/schematics](https://www.bitovi.com/blog/angular-upgrades-painless-migration-from-tslint-to-eslint)

> Si quieres iniciar un proyecto con EsLint y cypress

[Como agregar Cypress and ESLint](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2021/09/30/adding-eslint-and-cypress-to-a-new-angular-project/)

> Asi que tu proyecto fue creado adecuadamente . Podes seguir los
> lanzamiento de nuevas versiones

[Releases](https://github.com/angular/angular/releases?page=8)